# Dynamically create SciPy curve_fit function

Tags: python, scipy, regression, linear-regression, scipy-optimize

SO noob here.

I am creating a wrapper around scipy.optimize.curve_fit for multivariate regression.
I was able to successfully run a vanilla version with two or three independent variables -

Two independent variables -

```
def fn(x, a, b1, b2):
    return a + b1*x[0] + b2*x[1]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fn, x, y)
```

Three independent variables -

```
def fn(x, a, b1, b2, b3):
    return a + b1*x[0] + b2*x[1] + b3*x[2]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fn, x, y)
```

The thing is, I don't know how many independent variables will there be in input and I don't want to iterate through all permutations of the function definition manually, which I also don't think is the best practice. So the question is **How to create the function `fn` dynamically here based on the input dataframe?**

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very elegant solution, but you can always generate Python code from strings using the `exec` command [like this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/). Then you can just generate a string dynamically for your function definitions and with `exec` actually create the function.